# Replace multiple words from sentence in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm writing a sentence in text-area field where I'm sending it for any spelling checks using API, which returns me a JSON of misspelled words, So How I replace words in a sentence based on word index?

**Im using AngularJS 1 and Javascript**

**Example:**

> "In publishing, art, and communicatio, content is the inforation and experiences that are directed towards "

**When I send to server it Outputs:**

```
{"4":"communication","8":"information"}
```

**Output to be needed in textarea as:**

> "In publishing, art, and communication, content is the information and experiences that are directed towards "

**ANGULAR JS CODE:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
              rows="10" ng-model="textcontent" required>
    </textarea>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.dataautocorrect = { 
        "data":$scope.textcontent
    }

    $http.post(autocorrect,JSON.stringify($scope.dataautocorrect)).then(function (res){

        $scope.response = res.data;
        console.log(res);
        console.log( "Auto corrected Data");
    });

}
```

So how do I replace spelling mistakes to correct ones based on JSON Word Index?

Comment: You need to grab your sentence and split it on whitespace, then replace the words at array index passed in JSON with the word corresponding to it. Then Join the array values back together and replace your textarea value

Comment: Can you send any links that might help me getting required solution, because I checked with alot, I'm more of getting based on charAt or index based on word but on word count based, Would be grateful if you suggest some links that will help me to solve @RyanWilson

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @georgeawg appreciate , But could you help me giving any hints so I can code in the required solution, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to split the words into an array and then replace the word on the specific index

```
//your string value from the textarea
var yourString = "In publishing, art, and communicatio, content is the inforation and experiences that are directed towards ";

//find the words in the string
var words = yourString.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g);
//words will then contain ["In", "publishing", "art", "and", "communicatio", "content", "is", "the", "inforation", "and", "experiences", "that", "are", "directed", "towards"]

//results from the spelling check api
var correctWords = {"4":"communication","8":"information"};

//loop through the keys in the json object and replace the misspelled word with the corrected word
Object.keys(correctWords).forEach(function(key) {
  var wordToReplace = words[key];
  yourString = yourString.replace(wordToReplace, correctWords[key]);
});
```

Comment: Extremely elegant!